# What does a sudden increase in accuracy during epoch training show about my model?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

I am learning Convolution Neural Network now and practicing it on kaggle digit recognizer (MNIST) dataset.
While training the data, I noticed that inspite of initial gradually growing accuracy, in between there was a huge jump i.e from 0.8984 to 0.9814.

As a beginner, I want to investigate what does this jump really show about my model. Here is the image of the epochs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbyZk.png)
I have circled the jump in yellow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors type of regularization you are using, your NN architecture, how you are training (batch size, type of data splitting). Since MNIST is a simple dataset for CNNs hence they are easily able to achieve this much accuracy. There is also an accuracy jump from epoch 1 to 2 i.e. from 20% to 80%.

Comment: @techytushar the first one (which is showing 0.2 accuracy) is actually experimental and not a full-fledged epoch. But thanks for the insight. Is a smoother growth in accuracy good for training?

Answer (score 0):

As the loss gradually starts to decrease, this create an impact on fitting of the model. The cost function makes the loss go down, which directly creates an impact on the fitting of model. Better the fitting of model into training data, better the accuracy (which we can easily see as the accuracy increases with the reduction in loss). There is almost a difference of 0.08 in your consecutive loss function which is enough for the model to fit more from the current state.

Now as the model progresses, we try it on the testing dataset because the real world data is nothing like the data we trained it on.

However, a higher accuracy might not always be good as the model is considered to be over-evaluated which is also known as **overfitting** which means the model is performing too well that it can't handle any little changes. Therefore, a correct balance between learning rate and epochs are required in order to predict the classes correctly. It also depends on the architecture, Optimizing function which make sure the oscillations are low and numerous other things.